# Android add new/different fragment to the backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-menu, android-navigation, fragmentmanager

I have a navigation drawer setup which on menu item click will replace the fragment container with whichever new fragment is being chosen in the menu:

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        switch (id) {
            case R.id.nav_new:
                if (subInfo.isEmpty()){
                    addFragment(new NewFragment(), id);
                } else {
                    addFragment(new SubjectInfoFragment(), id);
                }
                break;
            case R.id.nav_start:
                addFragment(new StartFragment(), id);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_save:
                addFragment(new SaveFragment(), id);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_raw:
                addFragment(new RawFragment(), id);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_accelerometer:
                addFragment(new AccelerometerFragment(), id);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_accelerometerWorld:
                addFragment(new AccelerometerWorldFragment(), id);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_gyroscope:
                addFragment(new GyroscopeFragment(), id);
                break;
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```

And the method for adding fragments:

```
public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, int id) {
        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

            if (fragmentManager.getFragments() == null) {
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName())
                        .commit();
            } else {
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName())
                        .addToBackStack(Integer.toString(id))
                        .commit();
            }
        }
    }
```

In one of my fragments (`NewFragment()`) there is a data insert form, the id of that menu item is `nav_new`. When the submit button is clicked, the `addFragment` method is called to direct the user to another fragment (`StartFragment()`) in my app:

```
mainActivity.addFragment(new StartFragment(), R.id.nav_new);
```

However, the above will add the data insert form to the backstack. Once the user has submitted the form, I don't want them to be able to press back to get back to the submission form. Instead I want to direct them to another fragment (`SubjectInfoFragment()`) which contains a summary of the information they've entered

I've designed my `onNavigationItemSelected` method to support this. When the `nav_new` menu item is clicked, it checks to see whether the user has already entered any info. If they haven't, then a transaction takes place that takes them to `NewFragment` to enter form info. If they have, `SubjectInfoFragment` is shown instead to display a summary of their previously entered info

I have to direct them to `StartFragment` on form submit, but then the old form fragment is added to the backstack, which is undesireable

After form submission, how do I handle fragment transactions such that the back button will take them to a completely new fragment (`SubjectInfoFragment`) instead of taking them back to the form submission page?

Or in the worst case scenario, if I cant add an entirely new fragment to the backstack, how can I at least prevent users from pressing back to the form submit page?

Answer (score 0):

you should use the following line to add fragment to backstack:

```
getFragmentManager.addToBackStack(tag or null);
```

Comment: Not including a message in the call to `addToBackStack` doesn't prevent the fragment from being added to the back stack though...

Comment: What you want to do? you want to add fragment to backstack or not?

Comment: No, I thought I specified pretty clearly what I wanted in the question. I want to add ANOTHER fragment to the backstack instead of the one I'm currently on. This way users cannot press the back button to go back to the form submission fragment, and instead will see the summary fragment

Comment: Got your point, if you are using slider menu than its not possible for you to add another fragment, Otherwise you can add multiple fragments using `addToBackStack` method.